# hierarchical clustering default behavior in R?

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

when you do the following clustering in R:

```
> d <- dist(as.matrix(mtcars))
> hc <- hclust(d)   
> plot(hc)
```

you get a tree with nodes that have unequal branch lengths. in ordinary hierarchical clustering (upgma) all the lengths have to be equal. can someone please explain the default behavior of hclust, and how it yields non-equal lengths?  thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "unequal branch lengths"? Du you mean the length from the dendrograms root to the leafs or the length between two branching points?

Comment: @Beasterfield: the length from the root to the leafs which in upgma is always equal for all leafs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think too, that this is an odd behaviour. But it is not caused by `hclust` but `plot.hclust` instead. If you look at the help (`? plot.hclust`), you'll find the `hang` parameter which is set to 0.1 on default:

> The fraction of the plot height by which labels should hang below the rest of the plot. A negative value will cause the labels to hang down from 0.

Accordingly, the behaviour known from upgma can be achieved with

```
plot( hc, hang = -1 )
```

I'd guess that the two different behaviours are the result of different definitions which height should be assigned to a cluster which contains only one observation, i.e. is not merged with another. Obviously the definition here is: They don't have a height at all. Formally, it would be correct to plot them with `hang = 0`. But since this looks ugly, I guess that `hang = 0.1` is set as default.

In any case, you'll get branches with unequal lengths with `hang >= 0`.

Comment: I think I understand `hang` but I still don't see why it would apply differentially to some leafs and not others... you're right that `hang=-1` fixes the problem

Comment: @user248237dfsf how does it apply differentially? Can you give an example? It puts the leaf at the height of the cluster within it is merged  - `hang` * total height of the dendrogram.